# Javascript - How to config current date format as dayName - dd - monthName - yyyy?

Tags: javascript, date

I managed to create the format **dayName - dd - monthName - yyyy** manually with 2 arrays, one for *days[]* and one for *months[]* and output the message just like i want the format to be. But is there any easier and automated way to do this?

> Something like:

```
var d = new Date(dayName-dd-monthName-yyyy);`
```

> My Code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var d = new Date();

//Javascript starts days from 0, Sunday = 1st day of the week = days[0]
var days = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday",
"Thurday","Friday","Saturday"];
var months = ["January","February","March","April","May",
"June","July","August","September","Octomber","November","December"];

//output of the Current date in format dayName-dd-monthName-yyyy
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = days[d.getDay()] + " " + 
d.getDate() + " " + months[d.getMonth()] + " " + d.getFullYear();

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Note: I can use non-english names for the days and months, it will be perfect if this can happen in your answers too.

Comment: You could try moment.js a really nice and powerful library.http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From My view, Use your own function , Which you have create. It will be working fast rather then working of used external libraries.

And if you want to work with js libraries. Then work with [date.js](https://github.com/datejs/Datejs) library.

Comment: In my experience performance is not much of an issue in date conversion. But reinventing the wheel and writing own stuff, which is in general more erroneous then well tested libraries is only a good idea, if you really need it due to performance issues.

Comment: Thanks @FrankEssenberger ... I appreciate with your comment . But i think our code is more reliable and also easily handle than tested library.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend moment.js, which is a slim easy to use library. It supports multi language so there is no need to hard code any day names. Also the time zone is important when you translate from a milliseconds to a human readable date:

```
moment.locale('de'); 
//set locale to german for example so Month October will be Okt or the LLLL //format will be Freitag, 24. Juni 2016 01:42

var iStart = your date in milliseconds 
var sFormat = "MMM D, YYYY";
var sTimeZone = "UTC";
var sDate = moment.tz(iStart, sTimeZone ).format(sFormat);
```

Comment: I would not call moment.js slim. For parsing and formatting, compare to [*Fecha.js*](https://github.com/taylorhakes/fecha).

Comment: You are right. Note js is not slim compared to your recommendation. The important thing IMOH is to use a standard libary for a standard task. Then you should pick the smallest one which fits your needs. Since I have used moment in the past I had the code snippet ready for copy and paste.

Comment: I also have a beef with using language  as a "locale" for regional settings, but that's not your fault. :-)